# Date Column shows "NaT" instead of dates

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, forecasting

Here is the data that I am getting output:

|  | Quarter | Sales | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Q1_86 | 1734.827000 | NaT |
| 1 | Q2_86 | 2244.960999 | NaT |
| 2 | Q3_86 | 2533.804993 | NaT |
| 3 | Q4_86 | 2154.962997 | NaT |
| 4 | Q1_87 | 1547.818996 | NaT |

```py
# Assuming you have a DataFrame named coca_raw with a column named "Quarter"
coca_raw[["Year", "Month"]] = coca_raw["Quarter"].str.extract(r"(\d{2})_Q(\d)")  # Extract the year and month
coca_raw["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(coca_raw["Year"] + "-" + coca_raw["Month"], format="%y-%m-%d")  # Create the date column

# Keep only the "Quarter", "Sales", and "Date" columns
coca_raw = coca_raw[["Quarter", "Sales", "Date"]]

# Display the updated DataFrame
print(coca_raw)
```

i am trying to apply this code but not working as the Date column shows "NaT" Instead of dates.

tried the code with proper format as well but not having expected result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61672306/pandas-to-datetime-return-nat see this post

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
current_year= int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")) #get current_year
df=pd.DataFrame({"date":["Q1_86","Q2_86","Q3_86","Q4_86","Q1_87"]})
df["date_v1"]=df["date"].str.split("_").str.get(1) + '-' + df["date"].str.split("_").str.get(0)
df["date_v2"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date_v1"])

'''
   date   date_v1     date_v2
0  Q1_86   86-Q1      2086-01-01
1  Q2_86   86-Q2      2086-04-01
2  Q3_86   86-Q3      2086-07-01
3  Q4_86   86-Q4      2086-10-01
4  Q1_87   87-Q1      2087-01-01
'''
```

As you can see, the years are rolling to the present by default. If the year value is greater than the current year, we can subtract 100 years.

```
df['final_date']=df["date_v2"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=x.year - 100) if x.year > current_year else x)
```

**Out:**

```
|    | date   | date_v1   | date_v2             | final_date          |
|---:|:-------|:----------|:--------------------|:--------------------|
|  0 | Q1_86  | 86-Q1     | 2086-01-01 00:00:00 | 1986-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  1 | Q2_86  | 86-Q2     | 2086-04-01 00:00:00 | 1986-04-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 | Q3_86  | 86-Q3     | 2086-07-01 00:00:00 | 1986-07-01 00:00:00 |
|  3 | Q4_86  | 86-Q4     | 2086-10-01 00:00:00 | 1986-10-01 00:00:00 |
|  4 | Q1_87  | 87-Q1     | 2087-01-01 00:00:00 | 1987-01-01 00:00:00 |
```

Now you can drop unnecessary columns: `df=df.drop(["date","date_v1","date_v2"],axis=1)`